# SSRS report that outputs the number of invoiced lines with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-tablix

I've never used SSRS before so I'm not too familiar with its capabilities. I need to make a report that is grouped by Division Code, and then counts the number of invoices that are the same (by Invoice Number), and displays that in a column (I called it Invoice Lines). I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

[image: Excel example:]

And this is what I have so far, I know that the Invoice Lines value should be an expression, though I am not sure what expression to use or how to get it to work. When I created the report, I put all the fields in the details section and the Division Code in the group by section using the report wizard, but I'm not sure if that's right either as its not displaying anything when previewed:

[image: What I have on the report so far:]

Image added of trying count expression from comment:
[image: preview]
[image: design view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have grouped it by invoice number, then just an `=count(Fields!Invoice_no.Value)` should do the trick. Just ensure that this expression is on the grouped column header and not on the details line itself.

Comment: I ended up doing the group by in the stored procedure because it took care of it just fine vs putting it in the report. Putting the count in the details line didn't display or count how I expected, I will edit the post with an image of what that looks like

Comment: OK. without looking at the design view, it's hard to tell where you have the expression for the counts. If you had it in the group header level, then it should have worked. as long as it is working for you... all good

Comment: I figured it out! I had to group by invoice number in the SSRS and leave the group by's in the stored procedure itself. I then put the expression in the group by header like you said. Thank you!